# Динамическая замена символа в форме

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я не js программист поэтому прошу помощи у вас, коллеги. Есть форма поиска, нужно чтобы при наборе текста в поиске "1" автоматически заменялась на заглавную латинскую букву "I". Как это можно сделать с помощью js?

```
<input id="search" name="results" type="text" autofocus>
<button type="submit">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так например:

```
$('#search').on("change paste keyup", function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(val.indexOf('1')+1){
    $(this).val(val.replace(/1/g,'I'));
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/iliailia1212/uq1jj991/3/

Comment: На мой взгляд лучше в таком случае обрабатывать событие onChange, чем onKeyDown.

Comment: @XelaNimed в вопросе написано `при наборе текста` то есть с клавиатуры, именно по этому реализовал так.

Comment: Да, именно при наборе. Все работает так как надо, благодарю, @Mr_Epic!

Comment: @Mr_Epic извиняюсь за невнимательность... Но как бы то не было, мало входных данных. Насколько я знаю событие onKeyDown не произойдет на touch-устройствах, хотя могу и ошибаться. Ваш код корректно работает если зажать клавишу "1"? Я хочу лишь сказать, что на мой взгляд лучше обрабатывать значение поля при onChange и без привязки к коду кнопки, а просто заменяя в значении поля единицу на желаемое. Иначе не избежать ошибок при вставки значения из буфера обмена или при использовании не стандартной клавиатуры, например цифрового USB-блока для ноутбуков. Надеюсь автор дополнит описание задачи.

Comment: и если выделить и ввести то не удаляется старое.

Comment: Кстати да, было бы неплохо если и при вставке текста "1" менялась на нужный элемент, забыл учесть этот момент.

Comment: @AstemirBoziev сделал + добавил замену всех "1" ,а не только первого, как сделано в другом ответе и обработку всех возможных изменений

Comment: Спасибо! А то, что после набора текста в форме поиска не работает сочетание ctrl+a это побочный эффект или его можно как-то избежать?

UPD.
Проверил на телефоне, там не работает Paste..

Comment: @AstemirBoziev исправил, добавил проверку на добавления "1", только после добавления значение будет изменятся.

Comment: Проверил на разных телефонах, на iOS Paste работает, на WP нет.

Comment: @AstemirBoziev не работает именно при вставке, я правильно понял? Попробуйте так: https://jsfiddle.net/iliailia1212/uq1jj991/4/

Comment: на WP просто не вставляется ничего, на остальных устройствах все ок.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36433/discussion-between-mr-epic-and-astemir-boziev).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var search = document.getElementById('search');
search.oninput = function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/1/g, 'I');
};
```

```html
<input id="search" name="results" type="text" autofocus>
<button type="submit">
```

Comment: `oninput` чуть лучше – он срабатывает и когда в поле Paste'ят содержимое.

Comment: @Sergiks спасибо за наводку. для тач-устройств, вероятно, тоже будет удобнее

Comment: в принципе, и тот и тот вариант срабатывает, но при "Paste", к примеру если в слове несколько единичек, меняются не все.

Comment: @AstemirBoziev если paste через правое меню мышки – не сработает клавишное событие.

Comment: @AstemirBoziev поправил, теперь и ctrl+v, и paste срабатывает при единичном или множественном повторении символа

Comment: Зачем объявлять переменную `search`, которая потом используется только раз?

Comment: @Sergiks для наглядности, ибо задающий вопрос не разбирается в JS

Comment: Теперь все ок. :) Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно и на чистом JavaScript, без jQuery, довольно лаконично написать:

```js
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('input', function(e){
  e.target.value = e.target.value.split('1').join('I');
});
```

```html
<input id="search" name="results" type="text" autofocus>
<button type="submit">Отправить</button>
```

Слушаем HTML5 [событие `input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input), которое при любом внешнем изменении поля ввода происходит. Строку разбиваем в массив по единичке, и собираем массив обратно в строку уже с "I" в качестве «клея».

Comment: Спасибо, за отклик! работает как надо! :)